# How to clear a list in a for loop so I can use the list over and over again

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

I have a dataframe with a column with a bunch of text in it['description'], and I am trying to create new columns that have only the words that start with '@' from the description column.

To do this, I created a new column that used str.split() to create a list of each word from 'description', and then I wanted to loop through each column and create a new list of just the words starting with '@'.

I am VERY new to python, so what I am trying might be dumb, but I tried to name an empty list, then create a for loop that would go through each row, clear the list, then append that list with each word that started with @, then fill in the 'only@' column cell with said list, then start over on the next row.

```
df = pd.read_csv("wildkardinindia instagram hashtag scrape (1).csv")
df2 = df[['id', 'username','description','pubDate']]

df2['only@'] = np.NaN
df2['listsplit'] = df2['description'].str.split()

xlist = []
for indx, row in df2['listsplit'].iteritems():
    xlist = []
    for x in row:
        if x.startswith('@'):
            xlist.append(x)
            df2.loc[indx,'only@'] = xlist
```

I basically just want the 'only@' column to have a list of just the @ words, but I get an error doing it this way.  "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable", although it does fill in the first cell appropriately.  Just leaves the rest of the cells in that row as NaN.

I can move "xlist = []" to after "for x in row:", but that will only get the last @ word (sometimes there are multiple words starting with @), since it is clearing the list with every item on the list.

If I can figure out how to clear that list in the for loop, I think I got this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for the help!

here is a pic for df2 to see what it looks like - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JA_Krzk2cJ2CkAY1eIDqNBxL3Nzh2fmi

Comment: You should show your full stacktrace (the entire error message).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to this:

```
for indx, row in df2['listsplit'].iteritems():
    xlist = []
    for x in row:
        if x.startswith('@'):
            xlist.append(x)
    df2.at[indx,'only@'] = xlist
```

Comment: Then I get ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterabl

Comment: @szabon show in your question what your `df2` looks like. A picture is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a different approach using lambda

```
df = pd.read_csv("wildkardinindia instagram hashtag scrape (1).csv")
df2 = df[['id', 'username','description','pubDate']]
df2.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)

df2['listsplit'] = df2['description'].str.split()

df2['listsplit'] = df2.listsplit.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i.startswith('@')])
```

this basically changed the listplist column to get rid of any item that did not have @ at the beginning.  Worked like a charm!